# How do I add a Sub Menu Item to a Google Spreadsheet Menu

Tags: google-apps-script

From this Tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial

The following codes adds a menu item and under that menu item a sub menu item.  This works correctly and I ham happy with the results.

```
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus1 = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus1);
}​
```

I would like to add an extra sub menu item and I have tried this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus1 = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  var subMenus2 = [{name:"Open GUI", functionName: "fLoadGUI"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus2);
}​
```

And I have also tried this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus1 = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"}];
  var subMenus2 = [{name:"Open GUI", functionName: "fLoadGUI"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus1, subMenus2);
}
```

Both my attempts above failed. 
I suspect I should use the "additem" method but I'm not really sure hence my question here. I wondered if anyone would be good enough to point me in the right direction.

cheers Tony
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need to add the menu once but can have multiple items in it.(separate objects with commas)

```
function onOpen() {
  var subMenus = [{name:"Send Status Email", functionName: "emailStatusUpdates"},
                  {name:"Open GUI", functionName: "fLoadGUI"}
                  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Help Desk Menu", subMenus);
}
```

Comment: Thank You! that's it!  There is a clue... I can see now in the Variable name: "subMenus"